# How to utilize whole cluster in pyspark job

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, scikit-learn, hortonworks-data-platform

I am having 5 node hdp cluster with 2 master and 3 slaves. I am running spark job from pyspark shell from master 1. But it is allocating only 2 nodes(m2 and w3) for job with driver process running on m1. How can I distribute the load across the cluster.

```
from sklearn import datasets
from spark_sklearn import GridSearchCV
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from spark_sklearn.util import createLocalSparkSession


sc= createLocalSparkSession().sparkContext
digits = datasets.load_digits()
X, y = digits.data, digits.target
param_grid = {"max_depth": [3, 6],
              "max_features": [1, 3, 10],
              "min_samples_split": [1.0, 3, 10],
              "min_samples_leaf": [1, 3, 10],
              "bootstrap": [True, False],
              "criterion": ["gini", "entropy"],
              "n_estimators": [10, 20, 40, 80]}
gs = GridSearchCV(sc,XGBClassifier(),param_grid)
gs.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: how much data you have? data is partitioned into fractions of 128MB as the default size(spark.files.maxPartitionBytes). Hence, if there is not enough data, all the executors will not get involved.

Comment: My dataset is not too large but still I want to use those idle nodes. How can I do that ? Should I change spark.files.maxPartitionBytes to lower value ? or any other workaround ?

Comment: definitely you can modify that config, but if there a subset of all workers can handle the data why the cluster should accepts the overhead of involving all of them.

Comment: The ultimate aim here is to reduce the processing time, when I ran above code on spark local mode, it took around 1 hr. But when I ran on cluster, it took around 32 mins with 2 executors. So if I use whole resources in cluster, may be it will take less time. I tried setting spark.files.maxPartitionBytes to 64 mb but still its only allocating 2 executors on two nodes.